# Comma separated Columns (List Agrigate) in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table structure as below:

```
FIELD_A  FIELD_B

1          C

1          D   

2          E
```

This is my table structure and data within it.

I wanted to have result like:

```
1   C, D

2   E
```

I had done it in oracle using list aggregation functionality as below:

```
LISTAGG(rtrim(RS.RECAPITO||' '||RS.NOTE), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY rtrim(RS.RECAPITO||' '||RS.NOTE)) TEL
```

But this is not working in sql.

How can i do it in sql?

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `STUFF`

```
SELECT
     [FIELD_A],
     STUFF(
         (SELECT ',' + [FIELD_B]
          FROM TableName
          WHERE [FIELD_A] = a.[FIELD_A]
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS FieldList
FROM TableName AS a
GROUP BY [FIELD_A]
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d890/2)